# Crontab shell script git pull and forever start

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, git, raspbian

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi to check a repo on startup and then fire up a node script with forever.

I got the second part working, but I tried a dozen git commands with no success.

Here is my crontab that I access like so:

`crontab -u pi -e`

```
@reboot /bin/sh /home/pi/code/script.sh
```

Now my script has `-rwxr-xr-x` access rights and goes like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/pi/code
/usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /usr/bin/git pull origin master

/usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /home/pi/.nvm/v0.11.11/bin/forever start /home/pi/code/server.js
```

Forever starts the server.js on reboot, no problem, but the repo never gets updated. If I run the script using `sh /home/pi/code/script.sh` it triggers git pull correctly...
I initially set up an alias for git pull to be git up like it is recommended, but figured it might be my problem and I went back to the simplest version I could. Still no success.

Any input is welcome.

EDIT: the output of the crontab indicates connectivity issue:
`Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org` how can I wait for network to be setup before I run the script?

Comment: could you check the mails of root if there is some error, and what error? (xmail if you like UI of 70s, "less /var/spool/mail/root" a still better "interface")

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? Doesn't the crontab belong to the user `pi`? Unless it is being run by root, that will hang, waiting for a password. In any case, try adding `2>>/home/pi/cronlog` at the end of the crontab command. Then, reboot and check the contents of `/home/pi/cronlog`. If anything is there, [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting help to debug and trying out Phlogi's solution without success, I decided to go back to the original crontab and just add code to wait for the network interface to be ready. Here is what the script looks like now:

```
#!/bin/sh

while ! ping -c 1 -W 1 bitbucket.org; do
    echo "Waiting for bitbucket - network interface might be down..."
    sleep 1
done

cd /home/pi/code && /usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H git checkout master && /usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H git up

/usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /home/pi/.nvm/v0.11.11/bin/forever start    /home/pi/code/server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using crontab, you should create a simple service that depends on network:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/XY

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          XY
# Required-Start:    $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Example initscript
# Description:       This service is used to start XY
### END INIT INFO


case "$1" in 
    start)
        echo "Updating XY"
        cd /home/pi/code
        /usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /usr/bin/git pull origin master
        echo "Starting server.js"
        /usr/bin/sudo -u pi -H /home/pi/.nvm/v0.11.11/bin/forever start /home/pi/code/server.js
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping XY"

        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/XY start|stop"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Put it into the service folder and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/XY
```

Comment: The issue with that is that this script would be "written in stone", I'd like to keep the script itself under source control in case I want to add commands to it later. (The idea is that I won't have direct access to the Pi). But I guess I can just have the init.d fire up a shell script!

Comment: Yes, then just put your commands in a source controlled script and execute only that from the service.

Comment: I'm trying this out right now